# how to get AVG for every record in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I need to get AVG for every row in SQL for example:

this is the first table

```
+ ---+------+-------------+
| course_id | course_name | 
+ ----------+-------------+
| 1         | a           |
| 2         | b           | 
| 3         | c           | 
| 4         | g           | 
+ ---+------+-------------+
```

This is the second table 
I need to get AVG for both id 1 and 2. the result for example:

```
+ -------------------+------+----------+
| course_feedback_id | rate |course_id |
+ -================--+------+----------+
|       1            | 4    |   1      |
|       2            | 3    |   1      |
|       3            | 2    |   2      |
+ -------------------+------+----------+
```

this is the final answer that i need

```
+ ----------------------+
| course_id | AVG(rate) |
+ -=======--+-----------+
|     1     | 3.5       |   
|     2     | 2         |   

+ ----------------------+
```

I tried this soulution but it will give me only the first row not all records.

```
SELECT *, AVG(`rate`) from secondTable
```

please help

Comment: Have you tried using GROUP BY?

Comment: and a bit more explicit: `SELECT *, AVG(rate) from tableName GROUP BY ID`  Just a note anytime you use an aggregate function, min, max, avg, count, sum etc... you really should include a group by.  While earlier versions of mySQL don't require it; you'll be more likely to achieve the desired results if you have them.

Comment: Well, you need to let there be a learning curve too.

Comment: On a sidenote: Even if this is just an example, you shouldn't use the column name `ID` for a column that is not the table's unique ID. This can easily lead to misunderstandings and wrong answers.

Comment: I suggest you `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` while you still have problems writing aggregation queries. Your query is invalid and this mode would have resulted in an error message that might have helped you. (Without this mode MySQL converts your query to something like `SELECT ANY_VALUE(id), ANY_VALUE(rate), AVG(rate) from tableName`, thus picking values arbitrarily.)

Comment: please take a look to the post again I explain it in the best way. plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.course_id, AVG(fb.rate)
FROM course AS c
INNER JOIN course_feedback AS fb ON fb.course_id = c.course_id
GROUP BY c.course_id
```

Comment: I get the same result as before. Please check on your end. Also, please mark the answer as correct once it works for you.

Comment: Please note that for the data you provided you won't get any results for course id #3 and #4 because there are no rows in the course_feedback table that match them. If you need them, consider replacing the inner join by a left or right outer join instead.

Comment: i just need to display like that I don't want result for 3 and 4 because no record registered. i will try again your code

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. You might want to check out some SQL courses in Coursera where you can learn more about SQL joins, which are an essential part of a developer's daily work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `id`, AVG(`rate`) FROM `your_table` GROUP BY `id`
```

Comment: still same problem. just showing the first row only there is no id 2 in the result

Comment: @rook12320: The query is fine. Well, I'd remove all those unnecessary backticks, but it should work anyway :-) If there is no ID 2 in the results with this query, then there is no ID 2 in the table.

Comment: I ran the query using the provided example data. The results are OK, the row with ID 2 shows up fine. Please take a look to the this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/3nnx8936f1y3k14/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202018-11-26%2012.13.38.png?dl=1. You should be able to get similar results.

Comment: thank you, I just update the post please take a look to the post again. i think the post is more clear than before

Comment: @rook12320: This answer is still correct. You don't need a join as in the answer you accepted. Just `select course_id, avg(rate) from course_feedback group by course_id`. This is exactly the query posted by danielperaza, only with the names adjusted to your updated request.

Comment: yes it correct if i have select course_id only from 1 table. but i have 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

`Select course_id,t2.rate from table1 where course_id,rate in (Select course_id,avg(rate) as rate from table group by course_id t2)`

> When you have multiple entries/redundant entries and you want to find some aggregation per each as in this case you got id containing redundant records, In such cases always try to use `group by` as group by as the name says will group records of the column to which it is applied and if you apply aggregation `avg in this case` will be groupwise column to which it is being applied not as a whole like for id 1 we have 2 redundant entries so itll apply avg(id1_entries)..likewise as a group.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. actually I have 2 tables. first table has id and rate and in the second table has table_id and  names I just want to merge them together and get the AVG for every id. I tried the same query that you have mention it but doesn't work

Comment: Where is the second table ? and what is the error you got from the query which i just mentioned if you can share the error

Comment: I just update the post please take a look to the post again. I really thank you for your time

Comment: what is the error. try to replace rate to t2.rate and check if it works